# The ManyToOne / OneToOne Association

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine

I have a entity Product that contains two fields urlTracking and urltrackingDoc of type Urltracking and entity Urltracking that contains product.
I need a relationship between Product and Urltracking eg OneToOne ManyToOne.

the problem is when i am looking for the urlTracking by id i get the product well filled but when i search urlTrackingDoc by id i get the product null

```php
/**
 *@ORM\Table(name="product")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\ProductBundle\Repository\ProductRepository")
 */
class Product{


    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @var int
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @var UrlTracking $urlTracking
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\UrlTrackingBundle\Entity\UrlTracking", inversedBy="product")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="url_tracking_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $urlTracking;

    /**
     * @var UrlTracking $urlTrackingDoc
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\UrlTrackingBundle\Entity\UrlTracking", inversedBy="product")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="url_tracking_doc_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $urlTrackingDoc;

    //...
}

/**
 *@ORM\Table(name="url_tracking")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\UrlTrackingBundle\Repository\UrlTrackingRepository")
 */
class UrlTracking{


    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @var int
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var Product
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\ProductBundle\Entity\Product", mappedBy="urlTracking")
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\ProductBundle\Entity\Product", mappedBy="urlTrackingDoc")
     */
    private $product;
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to have 2 product attributes in UrlTracking entity, for example `$product` and `$productDoc` each one with its own doctrine mapping.

Comment: but it's the same product

Comment: I understand so maybe your have to change your model (maybe store the "doc" in UrlTracking entity...)

Comment: Or use OneToMany or something else

Comment: I separated orm OneToOne relationships between two variables `$product` and `$productDoc` that share a single accessor (get / set)